# Can I ask about Lumber Tycoon 2 on Arqade?

Tags: support, allowed-questions

Sorry but I don't have enough reputation to ask this question on meta so I an asking it over here.

The question is:

Is Lumber Tycoon 2 a suitable game for this site? It's a multiplayer game based on Roblox.

Comment: You don't need any reputation to ask on meta. And almost any game is on-topic here.

Comment: From what I can tell, it's a mod of Roblox.  Is that correct?  Then, yes, you can ask about it.

Comment: be sure to take a look at the [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) as a question about a game doesn't make it automatically on-topic, for instance we don't accept questions on pirating a game or doing anything that violates the Terms and Conditions and questions asking "can my PC play this game" are generally poorly received by the community

Comment: 1. Don't ask meta questions on the main site. 2. Why would it not be allowed? 3. A game on a computer, console, phone, etc. is always a video game. That is its definition.

Comment: so can i ask it and i didn't know that it was free to post questions on meta I taught that it would be a 5 reputation like other sites but can I ask question about the definition-video game -lumber tycoon 2???

Comment: @Fabian - a user needs at least [5 reputation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) to post on meta.

Comment: Really? Why is that so?

Comment: Btw, you can always ask on meta.stackexchange.com. Better than on the main gaming site.

Comment: @Fabian Questions about specific sites, like this one, are off-topic on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) and will get closed. Asking on the main site, then waiting for migration is the only way that users with less than [5 rep](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) (and [no posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274518/323179)) can get to meta.

Comment: But that's a bad way of handling that. Is there really no other way? What if someone wants to abide all the rules and sees no way to post such a question?

Comment: @Fabian - It's a perfectly fine way to handle it. All users with [Close and Reopen privileges](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) have the tools to manage it: Close -> Off-Topic -> This question belongs on another site... -> belongs on Meta. Given question traffic is higher on the main site, I imagine the 5 rep requirement exists so confused first-time users don't ask actual questions on meta sites, which would result in more community effort to move them over to main than the current situation.

Comment: In fact the ['Participate in Meta'](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) privilege listing goes over why there's a 5 rep minimum: *"...Because we allow anonymous participation, we require a small bit of parent site reputation to prevent spam, and ensure that meta is for active, engaged members of the community."*

Answer (score 2):

Hello and welcome to the site!

Yes, in general, questions to do with Lumber Tycoon 2 would be on topic here.

We do have some types of questions which aren't a good fit for us, so check out our [Help Center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) Article on [Asking](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more information, but generally, so long as your question is clearly worded it should do fine.

If a tag does not yet exist for a game, just tag it with the closest match, such as the console or platform that you play on. In this case, as Lumber Tycoon 2 is a mod of Roblox, tagging with the [roblox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roblox) tag would also work.

You can request a tag be created in the comments of your question after you post it.

I hope this helps and you get the answer you're looking for!